# Unable to see data from spark beeline for a hive orc table

Tags: apache-spark, orc

I have created an orc hive table as below:

- create table forest41 (id int, type string) clustered by (id) into 2
  buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

  insert into table forest41 values (1,'red'),(2,'white'),(3,'black');

Now when i am trying to see the data from spark beeline: It does not show me any data nor does it throw any exception.

Following is the query i ran :
select * from default.forest40 limit 10

But in the spark jobs console: It shows one of the jobs related to the above query - Skipped Stages (1) -- Spark JDBC Server Query

Answer (score 1):

You created hive table with hive's bucket feature but Spark doesn't support.

Go through this link http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#unsupported-hive-functionality

Comment: But after restarting the thrift server we will be able to view the data . Why is it so?

Comment: You mean. After restarting thrift server, you are able to get data. Can you please specify when you are not able to view the data?

Comment: Immediately after creating and inserting data into the hive orc table, you will not be able to view the data in spark beeline. Once you restart the thrift server and login to the beeline again you will be able to see.

Comment: Adding another observation from one of my team mates:

If we run the 'USE <dbname>' command before doing the 'select * from <tablename>' in the spark beeline, then also we will be able to view the data. And this does not require a thrift server restart.

Comment: May be this is a bug, raise in Spark Jira and also go through application log file to find some warning and error